# Is HashMap the best choice?

Tags: java, data-structures

This question relates to  using most efficient data structure for a part of a uni-project.
I have to store several instruction objects in a data structure. Each instruction has a unique int ID called Stage. Is HashMap the best choice to find the instruction i need fast ?I havent used it before but from the description it seems that using the int ID as key would make this run efficiently. If you can, please suggest a more efficient way to do it. Thanks

Comment: it's ok but not the best choice by far. You have to define 'best' 1st as well.

Comment: I am not very familure with the Java implimentation but as a rule hash tables are very efficient for finding a vaule when you have the key.  From what you have said I would expect it to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to lookup entries and not add/delete move, sort or do anything else, 
than an array is the fastest data structure for this.

Comment: But then he'd need to implement the lookup himself, which wouldn't guarantee fastest execution time.

Comment: if the key is only the position in the array, it would. I agree it is not really a useful implemenatition, but the fastest

Comment: I will read the instructions from a text then make objects representing instructions and store them in a data structure. once thats done i will be accessing each instruction many times but not adding /removing. Wouldn't it be slower to have a for loop each time i need to find an instruction ?

Comment: Object[] array = new Object[HIGHEST_ID]; 
Object myLookUpObject = array[ID];

Comment: @latusaki. If instructions index are just int values, then array is the better choice. Access is in constant time O(1). My answer isn't so good because t didn't think that your ids could be just integer.

Comment: yeah but "int ID as key" was an option for him

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Some kind of [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) seems to be the data structure of choice in your scenario.

Note that a [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does not maintain the order of its elements. If order is important to you, I suggest you use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (or perhaps even some [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) structure) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the best way because that way you can access the table in O(1).
Depends also on what's the type of your ids, maybe an array is enough (and even more efficient), but generally a hash-table is more flexible for these purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the domain of the keys, an Arraylist or a plain array may be even more efficient. But there are reasons not to use plain arrays too much.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID's are simply Integers and they are like 0,1,2..n then an array would be the best choice.

Comment: hm okay, i said exactly the same.. why did you get voted up and I have a big discussion going on? xD

Comment: sharpner, that gets you -1 for whining.